# Splitting string into array of words using specific words java

Tags: java, string, split

I want to split this String to give my desired output

```
sinXcos(b+c)
```

Gives output as

```
sinX
cos(b+c)
```

I know how to split a string like

```
200XY
```

using

```
token = 200XY;
String[] mix_token = token.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
```

But how can I use something like this on a string like

```
sinXcos(b+c)
```

or a String like

```
sinXcos(b+c)tan(z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String text = "sinXcos(b+c)tan(z)";
String patternString1 = "(sin|cos|tan)(?![a-z])\\(?\\w(\\+\\w)?\\)?";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString1);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
}



O/P:
sinX
cos(b+c)
tan(z)

2. Input :"sinabc(X+y)cos(b+c)tan(z)";
O/P :
cos(b+c)
tan(z)
```

Explaination :

S

```
tring patternString1 = "(sin|cos|tan)(?![a-z])\\(?\\w(\\+\\w)?\\)?";
1. (sin|cos|tan) -->start with (sin or  cos or tan)
2. (?:![a-z]) --> negative lookahead. check if the next character is not in between [a to z].
3. \\(?\\w(\\+\\w)?\\)?--> an optional brace followed by an alphabet followed by a "+" and another alphabet.
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply. What are the necessary import libs for me to try it?

Comment: if you are using eclipse, you could do ctrl+shift+o.

Comment: Thanx it worked. :)

But the second output is wrong :(

Comment: @gecco - Glad I could be of help.. :)

Comment: this only works if sin/cos/tan comes before a bracket.
Can you explain '(sin|cos|tan)(?!\\w+)\\(?\\w(\\+\\w)?\\)?'
So that I can get it to work as my desire.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56057/discussion-between-gecco-and-thelostmind).